# Accessing raw image sensor buffer with android NDK at different resolutions

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera

I'm trying to write a simple camera app for android that is able to record raw videos, I'm using the NDK camera api and a codec written in c++ that can save the raw (bayer filter array) images.
The problem is that with the camera api the only raw format available is AIMAGE_FORMAT_RAW16 and it only works at the sensor's full resolution which is a problem because it doesn't allow for decent framerates. I couldn't find a way to use the AIMAGE_FORMAT_PRIVATE with the AImageReader.

Is there a way to get RAW16 to work at lower resolutions or to get the data straight out of the sensor at lower res like all the other formats?

Also I've tried AIMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 which also doesn't seem to work with an image reader, this would only leave yuv and jpeg formats available to work with, I find that a little weird given that they both require extra computation compared to raw.

Additional notes. 
On my old galaxy s6 edge I was able to get a stable 30fps with a 16MP (5k) sensor, which is good, but on the newer s20 FE I could barely get 21fps with a 12MP sensor.
Targeting to support API 24 and greater.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.